# "http://localhost/" is being automatically added to https urls

Tags: http, url, https, iis-7

As the title suggests, `http://localhost/mywebapp` is being automatically added to urls within my application.

User clicks an **https** hyperlink, but instead of browsing to

```
https://correcturl.something.com
```

it goes to `http://localhost/mywebapp/https://correcturl.something.com`

ie the localhost part is being automatically added. I'm sure there is an IIS setting that we are missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be IIS. If you're forming your URLs improperly, I'm pretty sure the browser will handle redirect to "current url" + "redirecting url".

example:
if you execute the following in a javascript console, you will not get redirected.

```
window.location.href = "/http://google.com";
```

Running that off stackoverflow page sends me to https://stackoverflow.com/http://google.com

which is incorrect.

I'm assuming that if you're testing urls in some dev environment locally, you'll produce a similar result against localhost. I can't give you a better answer without more information, however I would begin by looking for something in your app similar to what I described.

Comment: Turns out the errors was at the developer level - unfortunately they didn't explain what they did to fix the problem...